# showing that system of equations can be solved using the implicit function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have to show that $xy^5 + yu^5 + zv^5 = 1, x^5y + y^5u + z^5v = 1$ can be solved in a neighbourhood of $(0,1,1,1,0)$. I can show that the two equations are solved if and only if $u=f(x,y,z,v)$ and $v=g(x,y,z,u)$ in a neighbourhood of $(0,1,1,1,0)$. My problem now is that I can't figure out how to make f and g only depend on $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Although you already accepted the answer, make sure you read my comment.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I've already flagged the accepted answer to be unaccepted.

Comment: @Faraad: Even though it's accepted, you can still edit it to make it correct. But I just wanted the OP to be aware ...

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: Flagging won't get your answer unaccepted, only fibo11235 can do that. If you want to help, you could learn the basics about Jacobians, and then fix your answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: To think I've answered many questions in multivariable calculus, differential geometry and don't know the as you say "basics about jacobians" is very insulting to me. I don't know the formalities in getting a question unaccepted, but it was clear that I misunderstood the question. I have other things to work on so I would of just liked to delete a response from me in general. Thank you from this comment though. Let's me know that I still need to go over the "basics".

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Ok. Sorry about that. I thought you had difficulties responding to Ted Shifrin's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bullet$  Let $M =\{xy^5 + yu^5 + zv^5 = 1\} \cap \{ x^5y + y^5u + z^5v = 1\}$

$\bullet$ Let $F(x,y,z,u,v) = (xy^5 + yu^5 + zv^5 -1,x^5y + y^5u + z^5v-1)= (r,s)$

$\bullet$ Then $M = F^{-1}(0,0)$ and $F$ is smooth.

$\bullet$ Letting $p = (x,y,z,u,v)$ we have,

$$DF(p) = \begin{pmatrix} y^5 & 5xy^4 + u^5 & v^5 & 5yu^4 & 5zv^4 \\ 5x^4y & x^5+5y^4u & 5z^4v & y^5 & z^5  \end{pmatrix}$$

$\bullet$ Show that this matrix has rank $2$, which will imply by the level-set theorem, that $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $3$.

$\bullet$ Hence we can allow $(u,v)$ to be our dependent variables. Since $M$ is a manifold, and $(x,y,z,u,v)$ give the coordinates on $M$, we must have that each coordinate is smooth i.e $u = g(x,y,z)$ and $v = h(x,y,z)$ where $h,g$ are smooth. To show that this is in fact true, we use the inverse function theorem on the map,

$$ T(\textbf{x}) = \begin{pmatrix}  \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}  & \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} \end{pmatrix} (\textbf{x})$$

i.e showing $\textbf{det}(T) \not = 0$ implies $F$ is a local diffeomorphism and now get your result.

Comment: This is not right. First, $F\colon\Bbb R^5\to\Bbb R^2$. To express $F^{-1}(0)$ locally as a graph over the $(x,y,z)$-plane, we need to write for $(u,v)$ locally as a smooth function of $(x,y,z)$.  So you need to make sure the $2\times 2$ determinant $$\left|\begin{matrix}\partial F_1/\partial u & \partial F_1/\partial v \\ \partial F_2/\partial u & \partial F_2/\partial v\end{matrix}\right|$$ is non-vanishing.

Comment: Faraad, this isn't right. The level set is a $3$-dimensional manifold, so you need three independent and two dependent variables.